# Как заменить текст в HTML c помощью JS, обращаясь к классу элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Допустим, у меня есть условная шапка сайта:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">Наша компания</div>
  <div class="children">Вакансии</div>
  <div class="children">Наша почта</div>
</div>
```

И я хочу, чтобы с помощью javascript текст при медиа запросе @media (max-width: 768px) заменялся на следующий:

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">Мы</div>
  <div class="children">Работа</div>
  <div class="children">Контакты</div>
</div>
```

Как мне это сделать, используя JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще это можно сделать и без js, но вариант с JS:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="global-alert-queue" class="layout-wrapper">
    <div class="alert success animate-in" role="alert">
        Your submission was successful.
        <button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button" onClick="changeText()">Change</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
    function changeText() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("animate-in")[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "Change Text";
}
```

Источник: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30860282/javascript-modify-the-text-inside-the-div-class

Вариант с Jquery:

```
$('.divName').html('Замена текста внутри DIV');
```

Вариант с CSS:

Добавить в шапку оба ваших вариантов и скрыть одну из них:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">Наша компания</div>
  <div class="children">Вакансии</div>
  <div class="children">Наша почта</div>
</div>

<div class="mobile">
  <div class="children">Мы</div>
  <div class="children">Работа</div>
  <div class="children">Контакты</div>
</div>

@media (max-width: 768px) {
 .mobile {
  display: none;
 }
}
```

Ну чтобы можно было скрыть один из них смотря на размер через CSS.

Comment: Спасибо! Сделал все-таки без JS, используя CSS, так получилось проще всего) Кстати, не подскажите одну вещь: если делать то, что я спрашивал в вопросе с помощью фреймворка, то можно ли выполнить эту задачу не с помощью jquery, как Вы показывали, а с помощью React? Или эти фреймы все-таки для немного разных задач?

Comment: К сожалению опыта в react у меня нет, но вы можете создать отдельный "топик" с тегом react и вам обязательно помогут :)